# Probably in this context

Tags: meaning

I have a question about the usage of probably.

Let's say you are at a party. You see 3 people - Person A, Person B, and Person C. Person A is your friend, though you don't really know Person B and Person C. You are certain Person A knows your name (as you are friends), though you only consider it likely that Person B and Person C know your name.

You walk up to them:

YOU: "You three probably know my name." = "I consider it likely you three know my name."

Would **"You three probably know my name."** work? I'm not sure if you would use it as you know that one of the three know your name for sure. Is there a different sentence? Would this one work?

Comment: There is no reason why *probably* cannot be a subset of *certain*. If I know for a fact that something is true, it's still correct to say that it's *probably* true. That it's not the normal way of expressing it does not invalidate it. If I say that my father *probably* knows my name, that's true—he probably does.

Answer (score 0):

If you rephrase it to **You three probably all know my name** you say that there is a chance that *all* three (as a single unit) know your name.

**You three probably know my name** sounds like that for each person there is a chance that (s)he knows your name, but you already know that one of them knows it. It can be interpreted in both ways.

Comment: Does "You three probably know my name" = "There is a high chance the 3 of you know my name."?

Comment: That is how I interpret it, but I am not sure there is an official rule.

Comment: But isn't saying "There is a high chance the 3 of you know my name." mean that there is a high chance that all 3 of them know my name? not just individually?

Comment: Your sentence can be interpreted in both ways, but if you input **all** you are explicitly saying that all three (as a single unit) probably knows your name.

Comment: @JuliN If the answer is acceptable, please mark it as answer.